# Would someone be able to test my website checkout in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Would someone be able to test my website checkout in IE7?  It is www.FoundersTelecom.com.  Please add any item to your cart and try to check out.  A military customer with super old browser just reported that the checkout screen formatting is all messed up and unusable.  I am unable to test on that browser.  Thank you so much!! 
Denise

Answer (score 0):

Best practices dictate that you shouldn't cater to users that are still running browsers that are no longer supported. Microsoft dropped support for IE7 a long time ago, and allowing users to use deprecated browsers will open you up to security issues. 
That being said, check out IETester if you are a Windows user. It will emulate older versions of IE.